# Unity3d editor: how to prevent changes from being undone upon exiting play mode?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Apparently this is some beginner's question (and that I am) but it's driving me crazy and I couldn't find any mention:

*I Occasionally forget to exit **Play mode** and go on building my UI making objects and changes, only to realize that I'm still in **Play Mode** and as soon as I unpress the play button, these will be purged!* I suppose the **Unity Editor** has its reasons for allowing editing of Scripts/Scenes while in **Play Mode** (would be happy to hear some examples-maybe testing scenes?) but my main question here is:

Is there some way for me to prevent this behavior? Or at least some trick that you use to prevent **me** from making changes while in **play mode**? (Other than becoming paranoid about it and checking constantly...)

Thank you

PS. *sigh* time to head back to Unity and rebuild that UI that I lost...

Comment: it's just how Unity is.  if you don't like it, don't use it.  Note that there are a number of things on the **asset store** to allow you to "save during Play" and other variations.  hope it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other Unity coders have had this problem before me and they came up with a neat solution.
Setting the UI to a different colour while in playmode "Playmode tint".

You can read the details here (originally posted 2009 but I have checked it still works in latest Unity 5.3):

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/9159/best-strategies-for-not-accidently-editing-whilst.html

Comment: Thank you @yinch! Your link to the unity discussions has given many good solutions - As you mentioned changing the *playmode tint* was probably the most helpful of all. Plus I read there a tip about enabling the *maximize on play* - thus hiding the panels altogether.

Answer (score 4):

There is no settings to prevent changing things during play mode but there are ways to reduce the chances of losing changes during play mode.

**1**.**Edit**->**Preferences**... -> **Colors**. Now, on the right change **Playmode Tint** to `red`. That will remind you you are making changes in play mode.

**2**.Click on the gear icon of each component you change during play then click **Copy Component**. When are done with playmode, select the component you want to keep its changes. Click the gear icon again and this time, Click **Paste Component Values**.

[image]

**3**.Write an Editor Plugin that will do that for you. This is hard but possible.

Use event to find out when entering playmode. Store all GameObject public **important** variables such as `transform`/`rigidbody` properties in a list.

Wait for the stop event to fire then ask your self which GameObjects to overwrite settings to. Then overwrite the properties of the selected GameObjects That's it.

Usefull APIs for this:

```
EditorApplication.isPlaying
EditorApplication.isPaused
EditorApplication.isPlayingOrWillChangePlaymode
EditorApplication.playmodeStateChanged += callBackFunc;
EditorApplication.HierarchyWindowItemCallback
EditorApplication.ProjectWindowItemCallback
```

**Note**: According to Unity [roadmap](http://unity3d.com/unity/roadmap/), a feature that enables you to save playtime changes is in construction and will be released soon but the above seems to be the only way at this time.

Comment: @gjttt1 Yeah that is pain and they began to work on it after getting many complaints. They also recently joined the .NET foundation and are working on .NET 6.  Too many good things coming in the future Unity version.

Comment: Thank you @Programmer for a beautiful and detailed answer!I can't "accept" two answers (I wish I could because your answer deserves it too) but at least I'm upvoting it!

Comment: @FotisK That's fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can select objects you want to keep while in play mode, copy them with `Ctrl + C`, and then just paste them back in with `Ctrl + V` after returning to edit mode. Then you can eithr delete the originals from the scene or copy values from individual components like @Programmer suggested.